# Getting rid of empty cpp files for interfaces in Rhapsody

Tags: makefile, rhapsody

In my project, I want to get rid of tons of empty and pointless cpp files for interfaces in IBM Rational Rhapsody.

Setting `CPP_CG:File:Generate` to `Specification` yields only header file generation of a class, which is almost what I want. But, the makefile (gpj) still looks for the *Ifc.cpp file. Is there a straight way to exclude these cpp files from makefile?

There is an option `CG::File::AddToMakefile` which does only work for component files. I found some info that it was working before but with Rhapsody 8, it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to force the suppression of the either header or implementation file of the interface using those properties. However!

Rhapsody expects to find the cpp file of the interface and suppressing it will cause problems with roundtrip function - Roundtrip doesn't just occur explicitly, it will also trigger implicitly by default when you save the project or change focus from code editor to model browser.

During this roundtrip, Rhapsody will try to "fix" the model by replacing the missing cpp file. This will be followed by roundtrip error messages. Disregarding the errors and continuing with roundtrip will probably cause duplicate elements and all sorts of mess.

In other words, what you're trying to do is not really supported and is a bad idea.